# Populate dropdownlist from database with multiparameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist from database, but the parameter (Div) has multiple values. I'm trying to use foreach loop but its not working. Is it actually possible or is there another solution for it? Maybe I should put it in the table and populate based from it? Would really appreciate any ideas and suggestion.

here's my code so far:

```
//strDiv is generated from another table in database, has multiple value and 
for each Div, it will have many product model

DCmdInquiry.CommandText = "Select  SG.DivCode from Staff as ST, StaffGroup as SG " +
                                  " where UserName = @UName and ST.SGroupID = SG.SGroupID";

        SqlParameter UName = new SqlParameter("@UName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        UName.Value = strTmpName;
        DCmdInquiry.Parameters.Add(UName);

        DRInquiry = DCmdInquiry.ExecuteReader();

        while (DRInquiry.Read())
        {
            strDiv = DRInquiry["DivCode"].ToString().Split(',');
        }

        ddlModelName.AppendDataBoundItems = true;

        SqlConnection DbConn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand DCmdInquiry2 = new SqlCommand();

        DbConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LDSTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        DCmdInquiry2.Connection = DbConn;
        DbConn.Open();

        DCmdInquiry2.CommandText = "Select ModelName from ProductModel where Div= @Div";

        foreach (string x in strDiv)
        {
            SqlParameter Div = new SqlParameter("Div", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            Div.Value = x;
            DCmdInquiry2.Parameters.Add(Div);

            ddlModelName.DataSource = DCmdInquiry2.ExecuteReader();
            ddlModelName.DataTextField = "ModelName";
            ddlModelName.DataValueField = "ModelName";
            ddlModelName.DataBind();
        }
```

Edit- My updated code, as suggested by Tim Schmelter :

```
foreach (string x in strDiv)
{
   Div.Value = x;
   DCmdInquiry2.Parameters.Add(Div);

   ddlModelName.Items.Add((string)DCmdInquiry2.ExecuteScalar());
   DCmdInquiry2.Parameters.Clear(); 
}
ddlModelName.DataBind();
```

Thank you.

Update:

After taking into account of Jon P's opinion and doing a lot of trial and error, I have come out with this SQL statement:

```
select distinct PD.DivCode, PM.ModelName, ST.UserName from ProdDiv as PD
Join Staff as ST on PD.ProdGroup = ST.SGroupID
Join ProductModel as PM on PD.DivCode = PM.Div
where ST.Username = '@UName'
```

that joins 3 tables to get the result. It works but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.

I still can't figure out the way to populate dropdownlist using multiparameter that yields more than one result. Tim Schmelter's way of doing it works for only one row (because it's using ExecuteScalar) and I need to yield all rows available.

Since I'm running out of time, I'll just stick with the above SQL. Perhaps its the only "correct" way to do it.

Comment: What error/exception are you getting and at which point in your posted code ?

Comment: You are binding collection to the `dropdownlist` in the loop, that wipes out previous data each time binding happens.

Comment: @HarveySpecter this is what I got at the ExecuteReader() :The variable name '@Div' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Comment: @HariPrasad I changed my code to bind the ddl outside of the loop, now it only binds the last value for the Div parameter.

Comment: Does your first query return one or many rows?

Comment: @JonP many rows. which is why i attempted the foreach loop.

Comment: Unfortunately you are paying the price for a flaw in your database design. You are now seeing why data should not be stored as delimited strings. You would be better off with a `StaffGroup_DivCode` table to maintain this many-to-many relationship.

Comment: You're right. I tried to do it this way because the database was already constructed years before I got in. I was assigned to add in new interface that users requested, which includes the new dropdownlist. Maybe I should try to discuss this with the guy who manage the database, see what we can do. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

- You are adding the same parameter multiple times in the `foreach`, that causes an exception. Either create the command in the loop, use `SqlCommand.Parameters.Clear` or change the `Value` every time.
- You also have to `DataBind` the ddl  after the loop or add the items one after the other.
- Also, use `@Div` as parameter name instead of `Div`.
- Finally, you can use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader` if you only get one result back:

---

```
SqlParameter Div = new SqlParameter("@Div", SqlDbType.VarChar);
DCmdInquiry2.Parameters.Add(Div);
foreach (string x in strDiv)
{
    Div.Value = x;
    ddlModelName.Items.Add((string)DCmdInquiry2.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Also use the `using` statement for everything implementing `IDisposable`, f.e. your connection. That ensures that all unmanaged resources are disposed and the connection gets closed, even on error.

Comment: This somehow works (I got the first row of Product Model for every Div), but there are more than one rows returned for product model for every Div. How can I populate every row? I tried the executeReader but it gives me error: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.  Thank you!